# Getting all possible combinations from a list of numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinatorics

I'm looking for an efficient way to achieve this:

- you have a list of numbers 1.....n (typically: 1..5 or 1..7 or so - reasonably small, but can vary from case to case)
- you need all combinations of all lengths for those numbers, e.g. all combinations of just one number ({1}, {2}, .... {n}), then all combinations of two distinct numbers ({1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4} ..... {n-1, n} ), then all combinations fo three of those numbers ({1,2,3}, {1,2,4}) and so forth

Basically, within the group, the order is irrelevant, so {1,2,3} is equivalent to {1,3,2} - it's just a matter of getting all groups of x numbers from that list

Seems like there ought to be a simple algorithm for this - but I have searched in vain so far. Most combinatorics and permutation algorithms seems to a) take order into account (e.g. 123 is not equal to 132), and they always seems to operate on a single string of characters or numbers....

Anyone have a great, nice'n'quick algorithm up their sleeve??

Thanks!

Comment: You are basically looking for the [Power Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of your list (which is mathematically actually a set, if all of its items are unique).

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802822/all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-values/41642733#41642733

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just increment a binary number and take the elements corresponding to bits that are set.

For instance, `00101101` would mean take the elements at indexes 0, 2, 3, and 5. Since your list is simply 1..n, the element is simply the index + 1.

This will generate in-order permutations. In other words, only `{1, 2, 3}` will be generated. Not `{1, 3, 2}` or `{2, 1, 3}` or `{2, 3, 1}`, etc.

Comment: @Henri's solution is pretty much an implementation of this idea, using LINQ.

Comment: @Nate Kohl Yea I just commented on that. Pretty clever! Gave it a +1.

Comment: +1 : a nice proof that the number of subsets of a given set of size N is 2^N

Comment: This is a awesome answer!

Answer (score 43):

Not my code, but you're looking for the powerset. Google gave me this solution, which seems t work:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
              select
                  from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                  where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                  select list[i];
}
```

Source: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#C.23

Comment: Just for clarification, this is my answer, implemented via LINQ. Which, I have to admit, is quite clever.

Comment: Power Of Linq, a moment respect for it.

Comment: Works, but only for lists with less than 32 elements due to Enumerable.Range's restriction of the 2nd parameter to type "int"

Answer (score 13):

This is something I have written in the past to accomplish such a task.

```
List<T[]> CreateSubsets<T>(T[] originalArray) 
{ 
    List<T[]> subsets = new List<T[]>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.Length; i++) 
    { 
        int subsetCount = subsets.Count; 
        subsets.Add(new T[] { originalArray[i] }); 

        for (int j = 0; j < subsetCount; j++) 
        { 
            T[] newSubset = new T[subsets[j].Length + 1]; 
            subsets[j].CopyTo(newSubset, 0); 
            newSubset[newSubset.Length - 1] = originalArray[i]; 
            subsets.Add(newSubset); 
        } 
    } 

    return subsets; 
}
```

It's generic, so it will work for ints, longs, strings, Foos, etc.

Comment: For a `List<int>` for example you'd call it as `var newList = CreateSubsets<int>(sourceList.ToArray())`