# Create all possible String permutations

Tags: c#, string, selenium

He is my problem. There is String "Case 1 V1: A, B, C...". Words "Case 1 V1:" - are permanent and A, B , C - are variables.
Meaning my String might be contained of many elements, usually three, sometimes 4-6 elements. I don't know the order of elements meaning one time it would be "Case 1 V1: A, B, C" the second time "Case 1 V1: B, A, C". 
I would like to make List with all possible string combinations.
Is there an easy way of creating all the combinations?

Comment: Whay have you tried? Show us some code

Comment: Maybe instead of doing that you should just check that your web page contains exactly three letters, and contains at least one A, at least one B, and at least one C?

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802822/all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-values-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Plue: That's all possible combinations, not all possible permutations.

Comment: @Rueven: Note that you should use the term "permutations" not "combinations" to describe your requirement. All combinations will include the empty set, "A", "B", "C", "A B", "A C", "B C" and so on.

Comment: @Matthew Watson yes I've been fooled by the title. But he can still use it and keep values with 3 characters

Comment: Changed the title so that it's easier for people to find in the future. Haven't changed the body of the question, so searching on "combinations" should still find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var head = new T[] { item };
        var tail = items.Except(head).ToList();
        var subLists = Permutations(tail);
        if (subLists.Any())
        {
            foreach (var subList in subLists)
            {
                yield return head.Concat(subList);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return head;
        }
    }
}
```

The following

```
foreach (var p in Permutations(new string[] { "A", "B", "C" }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", p));
}
```

yields

```
A, B, C
A, C, B
B, A, C
B, C, A
C, A, B
C, B, A
```

**Note that this has complexity in the order n! where n is the number of items in the list. So its fine for three items, but once you start getting into lists with 8 or more items there are tens of thousands of permutations.**

As I said above, I think it would be much better, rather than generating all options and testing them one by one, to look at what's actually there and see if it matches what you expect. Check that the list has the expected number of items, and then check to see if somewhere in that list each expected item appears at least once.

Comment: I've updated my answer to force the calculation of the tail with an extra call to ToList. This makes my solution of equivalent speed to Matthew's one. Presumably before I was recalculating the tail for each sublist, instead of just doing the work once.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have a `Permute` method lying around which I adapted to your needs.

It outputs the following, which I think is what you were asking for:

```
Case 1 V1: A, B, C
Case 1 V1: A, C, B
Case 1 V1: B, A, C
Case 1 V1: B, C, A
Case 1 V1: C, A, B
Case 1 V1: C, B, A
```

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            string prefix = "Case 1 V1: ";
            string[] possibilities = {"A", "B", "C"};

            foreach (var permutation in Permute(possibilities))
                Console.WriteLine(prefix + string.Join(", ", permutation));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
        {
            return permute(sequence, sequence.Count());
        }

        private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> permute<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, int count)
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                yield return new T[0];
            }
            else
            {
                int startingElementIndex = 0;

                foreach (T startingElement in sequence)
                {
                    IEnumerable<T> remainingItems = allExcept(sequence, startingElementIndex);

                    foreach (IEnumerable<T> permutationOfRemainder in permute(remainingItems, count - 1))
                        yield return (new [] { startingElement }).Concat(permutationOfRemainder);

                    ++startingElementIndex;
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> allExcept<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, int indexToSkip)
        {
            int index = 0;

            foreach (T item in input)
            {
                if (index != indexToSkip)
                    yield return item;

                ++index;
            }
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use typical **rank/unrank** technic for permutations (actually, in your case, you want *unrank* only):

```
  public static class Permutations {
    public static BigInteger Count(int size) {
      if (size < 0)
        return 0;

      BigInteger result = 1;

      for (int i = 2; i <= size; ++i)
        result *= i;

      return result;
    }

    public static int[] Unrank(int size, BigInteger rank) {
      if (size < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size", "size should not be negative.");
      else if (rank < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rank", "size should not be negative.");

      int[] digits = new int[size];

      for (int digit = 2; digit <= size; ++digit) {
        BigInteger divisor = digit;

        digits[size - digit] = (int) (rank % divisor);

        if (digit < size)
          rank /= divisor;
      }

      int[] permutation = new int[size];
      List<int> usedDigits = new List<int>(size);

      for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        usedDigits.Add(0);

      for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int v = usedDigits.IndexOf(0, 0);

        for (int k = 0; k < digits[i]; ++k)
          v = usedDigits.IndexOf(0, v + 1);

        permutation[i] = v;
        usedDigits[v] = 1;
      }

      return permutation;
    }
  }

  ...

      StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

      String data = "Case 1 V1: A, B, C";

      String[] items = data.Substring("Case 1 V1:".Length).Trim().Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

      for (int i = 0; i < (int) Permutations.Count(items.Length); ++i) {
        if (Sb.Length > 0)
          Sb.AppendLine();

        Sb.Append("Case 1 V1: ");

        Boolean firstItem = true;

        foreach (int j in Permutations.Unrank(items.Length, i)) {
          if (!firstItem)
            Sb.Append(", ");

          firstItem = false; 

          Sb.Append(items[j]);
        }
      }

      String result = Sb.ToString();
```

Output

```
Case 1 V1: A, B, C
Case 1 V1: A, C, B
Case 1 V1: B, A, C
Case 1 V1: B, C, A
Case 1 V1: C, A, B
Case 1 V1: C, B, A
```