# finding all possible sum of two arrays element

Tags: c#

I have two arrays and i am trying to get all possible sum of each element with other element of two array and index of each element

```
int[] width = new int[2] {10,20 };
int[] height = new int[2] {30,40 };
```

result should like this (value / indexes)

10 width0

10+20 width0+width1

10+30 width0+height0

10+40 width0+height1

10+20+30 width0+width1+height0

10+20+40 width0+width1+height1

10+20+30+40 width0+width1+height0+height1

And so for each element in two array

I tried using permutation but I get other output

Comment: Why don't you write some code and then show it to us...

Comment: Looks like a permutation of a *single* list `{10, 20, 30, 40}` but why do you then need this strange indexes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All Possible Combinations of a list of Values in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802822/all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Shouldn't 10+30+40 be there, too? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DrKoch iam searching for values and need to now where value come from or index of value component target=80 80 is height0+heght1+width0

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea  sorry just I missing to write it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more easy to get all combinations from one array than two arrays. And as we see, you need to store indices and array names along with the value of the  elements in collections. So, in my opinion the best option is to combine these two arrays in one dictionary, where the *key will be the value of the numbers* and the value will be **[ArrayName + Index of item]** (f.e width0, height1 and so on....)

So, let's combine these arrays in one dictionary:

```
int[] width = new int[2] { 10, 20 };
int[] height = new int[2] { 30, 40 };

var widthDictionary = width.ToList().Select((number, index) => new { index, number })
                           .ToDictionary(key => key.number, value => string.Format("width{0}", value.index));
var heightDictionary = height.ToList().Select((number, index) => new { index, number })
                           .ToDictionary(key => key.number, value => string.Format("height{0}", value.index));

// And here is the final dictionary
var totalDictionary = widthDictionary.Union(heightDictionary);
```

Then add this method to your class: ([source](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#C.23))

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
           select
               from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
               where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
               select list[i];
}
```

Then send your dictionary as an argument to this method and project this collection as you want with the help of the `Select()` method:

```
 var sumOfCombinations = GetPowerSet(totalDictionary.ToList())
              .Where(x => x.Count() > 0)
              .Select(x => new
                        {
                           Numbers = x.Select(pair => pair.Key).ToList(),
                           DisplayValues = x.Select(pair => pair.Value).ToList()
                        })
              .ToList();
```

And at the end you can display expected result as this:

```
sumOfCombinations.ForEach(x =>
{
      x.Numbers.ForEach(number => Console.Write("{0} ", number));
      x.DisplayValues.ForEach(displayValue => Console.Write("{0} ", displayValue));
      Console.WriteLine();
});
```

And, the result is:

[image]

Comment: @SherifElshahat Thanks formarking as an answer. By the way, I have updated my answer as you wish.

Comment: @SherifElshahat I have changed my code slightly to fit your requirements . Because, there could be some performance problems in the last updated version.
Good luck.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev thanks Farhad very much this code is more smarter

Answer (score 0):

This is a play off of `@Farhad Jabiyev`'s answer.

Declares a class called IndexValuePair. and uses `foreach` on `widthList` and `heightList`. to populate the 'Index' property of item instance.

*Note: Index is a string.*

---

### Class & Static Function

```
    public class IndexValuePair
    {
        public string Index {get;set;}
        public int Value {get;set;}
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
    {
         return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
               select
                     from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                     where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                     select list[i];
    }
```

---

### Main (*Console*)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] width = new int[2] { 10, 20 };
        int[] height = new int[2] { 30, 40 };

        var wholeList = width.Select(val => new IndexValuePair() { Index = "width", Value = val }).ToList();
        var heightList = height.Select(val => new IndexValuePair() { Index = "height", Value = val }).ToList();

        var iteration = 0;
        wholeList.ForEach(ivp => { ivp.Index = ivp.Index + count; count = iteration + 1; });
        iteration = 0;
        heightList.ForEach(ipv => { ivp.Index = ivp.Index + count; count = iteration + 1; });

        wholeList.AddRange(heightList);

        var sumOfCombinations = GetPowerSet(wholeList).Where(x => x.Count() > 0)
             .Select(x => new { Combination = x.ToList(), Sum = x.Sum(ivp => ivp.Value) }).ToList();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sumOfCombinations.ForEach(ivp =>
        {
            ivp.Combination.ForEach(pair => sb.Append(string.Format("{0} ", pair.Value)));
            sb.Append(string.Format("= {0} = ", x.Sum));
            ivp.Combination.ForEach(pair=> sb.Append(string.Format("{0} + ", pair.Index)));
            sb.Length -= 3;
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            sb.Clear();
        });

        var key = Console.ReadKey();
    }
```