# How to find all combinations of an List in sets of two?

Tags: c#, list, combinations

I've tried looking and I didn't find much for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Lets say that I have a `List<int>` that has around 50 numbers

```
List<int> _myList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
{
    _myList.Add(i);
}
```

How do I get a list of combinations based on an array for two?

For example
my result set would look like

1. `1,1`
2. `1,2`
3. `1,3`
4. `1,4`
5. `1,5`

and those are considered unique.  Is it possible to say `1,2` is the same as `2,1`?

Comment: Do you want the result to contain only unique sets even if the list contains duplicate values? Or: Do you know that the list never contains duplicates?

Comment: @olydis If you're referring to my source list, the source list will never have duplicates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802822/all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-values-in-c-sharp

Comment: Use the excellent [Combinatorics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) library by Adrian Akison at CodeProject.  Specifically, you would be using the **Combinations with Repetition** option.  I've personally used this library for many different types of projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that your source list is called `input`:

```
var output = new List<HashSet<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < input.Count; j++)
        output.Add(new HashSet<int> { input[i], input[j] });
```

In case you want to actually output the result to the console:

```
foreach (var result in output)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(output[i]);
            }  i'm guessing this is not how you write it

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", output[i]));` instead (the loop is fine, of course...)

Comment: I hate to open another question but if I have two of the hashsets above that you created how can I get the same combinations of those two sets?

Answer (score 1):

```
var sets;

for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
{
   for (int j = 1; j < 49; j++)
   {
      if(setc.Contains(new Pair(_myList(i), _myList(j))==false)
      {
         sets.Add(new Pair(_myList(i), _myList(j))
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need total combinations then there is a formula

```
totalCombination = n!/(k! * (n-k)!)
```

if **n=50** and **k=2** then

we can resolve it as **50!/2!*48!**

However to solve it programatically

```
for(int i=0;i<49;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<=49;j++)
    {
        //Collect all the combinations in the form of 'i, j'
    }
}
```