# Getting ALL possible combination of integers from an integer collection without fixed length in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, permutation

I have a problem I need to solve efficiently.

PROBLEM:
I have a 1 collection of integers of length(n). There could be duplicates.
I want to get all the possible combinations of those integers. The result is not a fixed length.

ie.

Given the collection of integers: [1,2,2,3]

The expected output should be:
[1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[1,2,2]
[1,2,2,3]
[1,2,3]
[2,2]
[2,3]
[2,2,3]

How to do this in c#, I would prefer a linq version, but other solutions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All Possible Combinations of a list of Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802822/all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-values)

Comment: Yes, that solves it. thanks.

Comment: Your solution leaves out [], [2], [3].  The first may not be valid.  The other two are.