# All permutations of a list

Tags: c#, combinations

I'd like to be able to take a list like this

```
var list=new List<int>{0, 1, 2};
```

And get a result like this

```
var result=
    new List<List<int>>{
        new List<int>{0, 1, 2},
        new List<int>{0, 2, 1},
        new List<int>{1, 0, 2},
        new List<int>{1, 2, 0},
        new List<int>{2, 0, 1},
        new List<int>{2, 1, 0}
    };
```

I'm not interested in sets with missing numbers, just combinations of the numbers that exist. Any ideas?

---

Also, I've looked into solutions like [Getting all possible combinations from a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319586/getting-all-possible-permutations-from-a-list-of-numbers) already, and they don't fit.

That one gives me something like this

```
var result=
    new List<List<int>> {
        // [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
        // serialized the result to JSON so it would be quicker.
    };
```

And it doesn't spit out all of the combinations.

---

Comment: What you're looking for is all the _Permutations_ of your list. This was asked plenty of times here before :) Here is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319586/getting-all-possible-permutations-from-a-list-of-numbers

Comment: That result doesn't include all the items, and it include permutations that exclude items. Tried them both and neither fit. I haven't been able to find any kind of working example that doesn't operate like the one you linked.

Comment: How are duplicates handled? What if you were given `0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2`?

Comment: Here is a nice article on permutations in C# [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G)

Comment: `[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]` exactly, and in my program I start with 1 instead of 0

Comment: Check this answer out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer?rq=1. You should be able to extrapolate it out to use a collection instead.

Comment: You are confusing the terminology. The Powerset is this: [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
 while you are asking for all the Permutations. The Combinations are of a degree, and would comprise the sub-set of the Powerset with number of elements equal to the degreee of the Combination, so the Combinations of degree 2 (ie, combinations of 3 choose 2) woudl be {1,2}, {2,3}, and {1,3}.

Comment: Voted to reopen the question as this q is about permutations while q marked as duplicate is about combinations.

Comment: I have code similar to the accepted answer and it is amazingly slow. The accepted answer is also amazingly slow. Did you ever find anything that is usefully fast?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try these extension methods on for size:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    if (sequence == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var list = sequence.ToList();

    if (!list.Any())
    {
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        var startingElementIndex = 0;

        foreach (var startingElement in list)
        {
            var index = startingElementIndex;
            var remainingItems = list.Where((e, i) => i != index);

            foreach (var permutationOfRemainder in remainingItems.Permute())
            {
                yield return permutationOfRemainder.Prepend(startingElement);
            }

            startingElementIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you win.

Comment: This looks good but where did you get the AllExcept method from?

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper I honestly don't remember from half a dozen years ago, my apologies.

Comment: I realize this is a bit late, but do note that the `AllExcept` method presented here can be entirely replaced with `list.Where((e,i) => i != startingElementIndex)`, which is significantly faster than manual iteration. Edit: And also doesn't suffer from problems if you execute the resulting enumerable multiple times

Comment: @MikeCaron elegant and succinct. Good call!