# F# -- The resulting type would be infinite error

Tags: f#

Here is a simple code to generate all permutations, based on implementation found here: [All permutations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150147/all-permutations-of-a-list)

```
let concatElement element sequence =
    seq {
        yield element
        yield! sequence
    }

let rec permute (choices : 'a seq)=
    seq {
        if Seq.isEmpty choices then
            yield Seq.empty
        else
            for choice in choices do
                let remaining = choices |> Seq.where (fun el -> el <> choice)
                yield concatElement choice (permute remaining)
    }
```

I get a compile-time error "The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and 'seq<'a>'" on `"yield concatElement choice (permute remaining)"`

What is wrong here?

Comment: What should the return type be? Assuming it should be `seq<seq<'a>>` you need the first argument to `concatElement` on the last line to be a `seq<'a>` but `choice` is an `'a`.

Comment: concatElement just appends one element to a sequence and returns seq<'a>, so yield concatElement should yield a seq<'a>, which in result produces seq<seq<'a>>. What am I missing? Or maybe I should pass a "head" around and concat two sequences?

Comment: If `permute` returns a `seq<seq<'a>>` then `concatElement choice (permute remaining)` is trying to concat an `'a` and a `seq<seq<'a>>` which is a type error. If you add an explicit return type to `permute` you might get a more useful error message.

Comment: I've cited another implementation but ignored a nested loop totally. Shame on me. I would prefer to change it to tail recursion but it doesn't seem to be straightforward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to `yield` an `'a seq` as a single element of a sequence which has type `'a seq`.  For that to work, then `'a` must be the same type as `'a seq`, and so on, so the type is "infinite" - you'd have to have nested them infinitely for it to "work".

I see in your answer that you recognised you have to loop through the sequence elements somehow.  You can, as you have, use the `for .. in` syntax to iterate through, or F# gives you the `yield!` operator which actually does this for you.  In this spirit, your answer could be written as

```
let rec permute (choices : 'a seq) (permBuilder: 'a seq) : seq<seq<'a>>= seq {
    if Seq.isEmpty choices then
        yield permBuilder
    else
        for choice in choices do
            let remaining = choices |> Seq.where (fun el -> el <> choice)
            let newBuilder = concatElement choice permBuilder 
            yield! permute remaining newBuilder }
```

Or, alternatively, we can use the `Seq.collect` function to automatically gather a sequence of sequences (of sequences!) for us, and we're left with nice functional-style code with no explicit iterators:

```
let prepend element sequence = seq { yield element; yield! sequence }

let rec permute input =
    if Seq.length input <= 1 then Seq.singleton input
    else
        let without element = Seq.where ((<>) element) input
        let permutations element = permute (without element) |> Seq.map (prepend element)
        Seq.collect permutations input
```

Something to consider, though: what happens if you have two elements which aren't distinct?  For example, what happens if you try to get the permutations of `[1; 1; 2]`?  Your current method can't handle this neatly - even if you improved the `without` closure, you'd get duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it

```
let concatElement element sequence =
    seq {
        yield element
        yield! sequence
    }

let rec permute (choices : 'a seq) (permBuilder: 'a seq) : seq<seq<'a>>=
    seq {
        if Seq.isEmpty choices then
            yield permBuilder
        else
            for choice in choices do
                let remaining = choices |> Seq.where (fun el -> el <> choice)
                let newBuilder = concatElement choice permBuilder 
                for perm in permute remaining newBuilder do
                    yield perm
```

As Lee've has commented, I tried to concat seq<'a> with seq< seq<'a>>. My code lacked a loop over permutations.