# return IList<IList<int>> is empty - why?

Tags: c#, list, permutation

The problem is to return a list containing all permutations of an array. For some reason the result list is empty. The truth is I'm 100% sure it has to do with me using IList or List wrong somewhere, but it was honestly confusing to have to return it as an `IList<IList<int>>` ...I feel like it would have been easier to just return `List<List<int>>` but I'm doing this off of leetcode and trying to keep the original signature that was written in the question. When currentPermutation.Count == nums.Length, I printed the values of the currnet permutation and it printed all permutations, so I know that currentPermutation is being filled with the corrent numbers..why isn't the result list doing it as well?

```
public class Solution {

    public IList<IList<int>> Permute(int[] nums) {

        List<IList<int>> listOfPermutations = new List<IList<int>>();
        IList<int> currentPermutation = new List<int>();
        int[] elementsSeen = new int[nums.Length];
        Permute(listOfPermutations, nums, elementsSeen, currentPermutation);

        return (IList<IList<int>>)listOfPermutations;
    }


    public void Permute(List<IList<int>> list, int[] nums, int[] elementsSeen, IList<int> currentPermutation) {

        if (currentPermutation.Count == nums.Length) {
            list.Add(currentPermutation);
        }
        else {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) {
            if (elementsSeen[i] == 0) {
                elementsSeen[i] = 1;
                currentPermutation.Add(nums[i]);
                Permute(list, nums, elementsSeen, currentPermutation);
                currentPermutation.RemoveAt(currentPermutation.Count - 1);
                elementsSeen[i] = 0;
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can see the link
[Permution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150147/all-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 4):

You add the same List over and over to the result. In the end you have n! pointers to the same, empty List (`currentPermutation` is empty in the end). All you need is to make a copy of the List for every permutation and add the new List to the result.

```
list.Add(currentPermutation.ToList()); //clone the list
```

"calling ToList() on a List" may seem a bit tricky, you are actually calling ToList() on IEnumerable, is that better? The point is to create new, independent List.

Maybe you do not exactly understand what List in C# is. List is an object. If you add it somewhere, you do not add it literally there, you just add pointer to this object.

Comment: Okay..changing that worked, but I don't really understand how ToList() fixes it..I'm calling ToList() on a List? What does that even mean?

Comment: @FrostyStraw I added some more explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: ToList is a Linq extension menthod, just to be even more clear. Beyond that, this whole data structure seems incredibly cumbersome to my tired brain.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Okay, I can more clearly see how I'm just adding the pointer to the same list 6 times. And the fact that I am removing the last element from the list each time I'm backtracking also makes sense as to why it's an empty list each time. Then calling ToList() just returns a new list and that's what is passed int other Add method of the list of lists..is this correct?