# Algorithm for Power Set / Sub-Set combinations required, but only for a fixed number of elements

Tags: c#, subset, powerset

It is an extension of this problem - Super set in a list:

[Getting all possible combinations from a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319586/getting-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list-of-numbers)

This helps, but returns all sub-sets:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#C.23

But what I need is to retrieve only the sub-sets that have a fixed number. I.e. say my list is a collection of numbers:

1
2
3
4
5
6

I only want the different combinations for an exact 4 numbers, i.e.
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,5
1,2,3,6
1,3,4,5
1,3,4,6
1,4,5,6
2,3,4,5
2,3,4,6
2,4,5,6
3,4,5,6

I am using numbers as an example, but in my solution I am dealing with other types of objects.

Comment: You could use the solution you provided, then check the length and !=  4 then get rid of it. I'm not that great at understanding Linq to be honest, so I have a hard time understanding what is really going on there.

Comment: You'd still do all the work of generating the sets you're going to throw out, but you could use a linq .Where(x => x.length == 4);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the solution you referenced by filtering on the length of the results

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSetOfLength<T>(List<T> list, int length)
{
    return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
              //because doing a count will iterate through the enumerable 
              //better to just convert it to a list up front 
              let setResult = ( from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                                where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                                select list[i]).ToList()
              where setResult.Count==length
              select setResult;
}
```

Here's a [link to a dot net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rzTkxR) that is using this code if you want to test it out

Comment: @SomeOne This will only work for `i < 31`, as `i` will overflow after 32-bits (integer limit)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want exactly 4, it's a relatively easy algorithm to write using nested for loops.

```
var set = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

for (int firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < set.Length; firstIndex++)
{
    for (int secondIndex = firstIndex+1; secondIndex < set.Length; secondIndex++)
    {
        for (int thirdIndex = secondIndex+1; thirdIndex < set.Length; thirdIndex++)
        {
            for (int fourthIndex = thirdIndex+1; fourthIndex < set.Length; fourthIndex++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format($"{set[firstIndex]}, {set[secondIndex]}, {set[thirdIndex]}, {set[fourthIndex]}"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need it to be dynamic and support different list sizes (i.e. it's not always 4) then it's probably easier to convert into a recursive call that recurses N times.