# Generating a powerset of a list where order matters

Tags: c#

I was looking for a way to create a powerset of letters basically to generate any possible letter combination but with a twist that order matters so ab != ba. I ran across a nifty bit of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319586/getting-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list-of-numbers/3319689#3319689) which I shamelessly pilfered. Here is my entire program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PermutationsHelper
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var ps = GetPowerSet(new List<string>() { "a", "b" });
            foreach (var item in ps)
            {
                string[] resultArr = item.ToArray();
                string result = string.Join("", resultArr);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
               select
                   from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                   where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                   select list[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[empty]
a
b
ab
```

But what I am looking for is:

```
[empty]
a
b
ab
ba
```

Any suggestions on how best to accomplish this? TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing all permutations of a string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

Comment: Tried that, the output for the above would be just ab, ba, although perhaps adding a for loop and printing the pieces should work. Wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the recursive approach as in the answer [Listing all permutations of a string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer/756083#756083) to get all possible combinations and permutations, including different orders. You define a method like `public static ISet<string> CombinationsAndPermutations(string input)` which works as follow:

- When the input is empty, return an empty list. *(nothing to do)*
- When the input is a string of length `1`, return a `Set` with the values `string.Empty` and the input string. *(recursion base case)*

For all the other cases you iterate over all the characters of the string and find solutions for this specific character or string position. You collect all sub solutions in a total result list and return it. The pseudo code will look like this:

```
for all positions in the string:
    get the character at position "i"
    get the remaining string without the character at position "i"
    get the solution for the remaining string (recursive call)

    add the solution to a total list of solutions
    add the solution to a total list of solutions, but add the extracted character from position "i" at the front

return the total list
```

That being said, the solution will look like this:

```
public static ISet<string> CombinationsAndPermutations(string input) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) {
        return new HashSet<string>();
    }
    if (input.Length == 1) {
        return new HashSet<string> { string.Empty, input };
    }

    ISet<string> result = new HashSet<string>();
    for (int i=0; i<input.Length; i++) {
        char letter = input[i];
        string remainingBefore = input.Substring(0, i);
        string remainingAfter = input.Substring(i+1);
        string remaining = remainingBefore + remainingAfter;

        ISet<string> subResult = CombinationsAndPermutations(remaining);

        foreach (string subStr in subResult) {
            result.Add(subStr);
            result.Add(letter + subStr);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

For the example input "abc", this will generate a `Set` with the following entries:

```
(, a, b, ab, c, ac, bc, abc, cb, acb, ba, bac, ca, bca, cab, cba)
```

Answer (score 0):

H/T to Progman, here is my solution:

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> biggestList = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "abc";
        char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();
        GetPer(arr);
        Console.WriteLine("Complete List:");
        for (int i = 0; i < biggestList.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(biggestList[i]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static void Swap(ref char a, ref char b)
    {
        if (a == b) return;

        a ^= b;
        b ^= a;
        a ^= b;
    }

    public static void GetPer(char[] list)
    {
        int x = list.Length - 1;
        GetPer(list, 0, x);
    }

    private static void GetPer(char[] list, int k, int m)
    {
        if (k == m)
        {
            string result = string.Join("", list.ToArray());
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                if(!biggestList.Contains(result.Substring(0, i + 1)))
                    biggestList.Add(result.Substring(0, i+1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = k; i <= m; i++)
            {
                Swap(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
                GetPer(list, k + 1, m);
                Swap(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```